# Can't get NON-english letters(text) from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am android developer and using PHP just for getting data from MySQL (so my PHP is very poor) and it always works but I come across that I can't get data with non-english letters

I have written that kind of question  [How to put in JSON Object non-english letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949215/how-to-put-in-json-object-non-english-letters)

but in that question I thought that problem was in json encoding, but it was not problem in json.(but now I know how to solve problem with json)
so I need just to get non-english text data from MySQL

I thought that problem was in database so I changed everything to `utf-8` , checked twice, made the same query in database and get expected result, so problem is in  php code.
then I researched and thought that maybe my php didn't maintain utf-8, and that line `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` to the top then create a simple String variable that consist non English letters and echo that variable, and it has showed me what I expect, so I think php support utf-8

so I think the only problem is in the part with `mysqli_query`

that is my code :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$con =  mysqli_connect(...);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE status = 'actual' ORDER BY id DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - TITLE:  " . $row["title"]. " -TEXT:  " . $row["text"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

it is my data base datas:
[image: datas]
 and structure:
[image: structure]

for all database

```
    MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
    MySQL connection collation: utf8_unicode_520_ci
```

I expected to get the same datas as in title and text columns  (you can see datas above)

but I get:

```
id: 4 - TITLE: ???????? -TEXT: ????????? ??????? ?????, ? ??? ????????? ?? ?????????
id: 3 - TITLE: A little bit... -TEXT: Just some more patience! And you will get this wonderfull application!
id: 1 - TITLE: �p�???�? -TEXT: Just wait a little bit!
```

I tried to write with all details of my problem, so help me with code, what I should add/modify (in which line?) to get expected result.
Thank you all in advance!

**SOLUTION HAS BEEN FOUND**

I should add 
`$con->set_charset("utf8");`

before declaring `$sql`

Comment: Does `$con` have the character set on it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829816/set-character-set-using-mysqli

Comment: Show the details of your connection to MySQL. You need to specify the charset when making the connection.

Comment: @user3783243 excuse me, I got that you mean that I should use `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` , but sorry my php knowledge is poor, where should I write it? after which line?

Comment: Your script is sending the meta tag before it attempts to send a header. You can't send headers after you've output text to the browser. This should probably be generating errors.

Comment: @user3783243 THANKS YOU ! I have found solution thanks to you, I should add `$con->set_charset("utf8");`
and it works!